# Map columns to its ID using TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that gets the duplicate records in a table. See below:

```
SELECT column1, column2
FROM table1
GROUP BY  column1, column2
HAVING COUNT(column1 +  column2) > 1
```

Now, I need to map column1 and column2 to its table **ID**, which I can't incorporate in the query above. I'm using TSQL, how do I do this?

Comment: What is the table ID? Please share the table structure and other relevant details.

Comment: table ID is the unique identifier or the primary key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code worked to get the IDs:

```
SELECT Id FROM table1 INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT column1, column2
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY  column1, column2
    HAVING COUNT(column1 +  column2) > 1
) thisTable
ON
table1.column1= thisTable.column1AND 
table1.column2= thisTable.column2
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `count` windowed aggregate to find duplicate `(column1, column2)` pairs along with their IDs:

```
declare @table table (id int, column1 varchar(10), column2 varchar(10))

insert into @table values
(1, 'A', 'B')
,(2, 'C', 'D')
,(3, 'A', 'C')
,(4, 'B', 'D')
,(5, 'C', 'A')
,(6, 'D', 'B')
,(7, 'A', 'B')


;with a as (
    select id, column1, column2,
        cnt = count(id) over (partition by column1, column2)
    from @table
)
select id, column1, column2
from a
where cnt > 1
```

Result:

```
id          column1    column2
----------- ---------- ----------
1           A          B
7           A          B
```